# MongoDB lookup when foreign field is an array

Tags: mongodb

I've searched the internet and StackOverflow, but I cannot find the answer or even the question.

I have two collections, `reports` and `users`. I want my query to return all reports and indicate if the specified user has that report as a favorite in their array.

**Reports Collection**

```
{ _id: 1, name:"Report One"}
{ _id: 2, name:"Report Two"}
{ _id: 3, name:"Report Three"}
```

**Users Collection**

```
{_id: 1, name:"Mike", favorites: [1,3]}
{_id: 2, name:"Tim", favorites: [2,3]}
```

**Desired Result for users.name="Mike"**

```
{ _id: 1, name:"Report One", favorite: true}
{ _id: 2, name:"Report Two", favorite: false}
{ _id: 3, name:"Report Three", favorite: true}
```

All of the answers I can find use $unwind on the local (`reports`) field, but in this case the local field isn't an array. The foreign field is the array.

How can I unwind the foreign field? Is there a better way to do this?

I saw online that someone suggested making another collection `favorites` that would contain:

```
{ _id: 1, userId: 1, reportId: 1 }
{ _id: 2, userId: 1, reportId: 3 }
{ _id: 3, userId: 2, reportId: 2 }
{ _id: 4, userId: 2, reportId: 3 }
```

This method seems like it should be unnessesary. It should be simple to join onto an ID in a foreign array, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-multiple-joins) which will give you `0` or `1` result and then use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to convert an array to single boolean value:

```
db.reports.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: { report_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$name", "Mike" ] },
                                { $in: [ "$$report_id", "$favorites" ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            favorite: { $eq: [ { $size: "$users" }, 1 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Alternatively if you need to use MongoDB version lower than 3.6 you can use regular `$lookup` and then use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get only those users where `name` is `Mike`:

```
db.reports.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "favorites",
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            favorite: { $eq: [ { $size: { $filter: { input: "$users", as: "u", cond: { $eq: [ "$$u.name", "Mike" ] } } } }, 1 ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using MongoDB 4. This makes sense. Do I have to do something different if all of those _id's are ObjectId's?

Comment: No, you just need to have ObjectIds in both collections

Comment: @mickl what if the foreignField is an array of objects, not just strings? in this case, what if favorites contained both the `name` and `id`?

Comment: @AbeCaymo can you open a new question and link it here?