# Find documents matching ObjectIDs in a foreign array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongojs

I have a collection `Users`:

```
{
  _id: "5cds8f8rfdshfd"
  name: "Ted"
  attending: [ObjectId("2cd9fjdkfsld")]
}
```

I have another collection `Events`:

```
{
  _id: "2cd9fjdkfsld"
  title: "Some Event Attended"
},
{
  _id: "34dshfj29jg"
  title: "Some Event NOT Attended"
}
```

I would like to return a list of all events being attended by a given user. However, I need to do this query from the `Events` collection as this is part of a larger query.

I have gone through the following questions:

- [$lookup on ObjectId's in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967482/lookup-on-objectids-in-an-array) - This question has the array as a local field; mine is foreign
- [MongoDB lookup when foreign field is an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54617074/mongodb-lookup-when-foreign-field-is-an-array-of-objects) - The array is of objects themselves
- [MongoDB lookup when foreign field is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53286146/mongodb-lookup-when-foreign-field-is-an-array)

I have tried various ways of modifying the above answers to fit my situation but have been unsuccessful. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286419/2662227) from the third question gets me closest but I would like to filter out unmatching results rather than have them  returned with a value of 0.

My desired output:

```
[
  {
    _id: "2cd9fjdkfsld"
    title: "Some Event Attended"
  },
]
```

Comment: What does your desired output document look like?

Comment: Updated with desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be like this:

```
db.getCollection('Events').aggregate({
    $lookup: // join
    {
        from: "Users", // on Users collection
        let: { eId: "$_id" }, // keep a local variable "eId" that points to the currently looked at event's "_id"
        pipeline: [{
            $match: { // filter where
                "_id": ObjectId("5c6efc937ef75175b2b8e7a4"), // a specific user
                $expr: { $in: [ "$$eId", "$attending" ] } // attends the event we're looking at
            }
        }],
        as: "users" // push all matched users into the "users" array
    }
}, {
    $match: { // remove events that the user does not attend
        "users": { $ne: [] }
    }
})
```

You could obviously get rid of the `users` field by adding another projection if needed.

Comment: Which title? The event title? You could simply add another pipeline stage `$project: { "title": 0 }`

Comment: Sorry, I was testing on the remote server. Yes, the event title...adding a projection to the pipeline does not do anything. Do I need to unwind or something first?

Comment: What does your result document look like? If it has a `title` field on the root level and you add the projection stage mentioned above at the end of your pipeline then this will definitely eliminate the field from the output.

Comment: Oh, it was that; I thought I'd tried that but I guess I had still been on remote. Thanks.